# html select option in internet explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have the following code ;

```
              <label for="courseLevel">Level</label>
              <select name="courseLevel" id="courseLevel">
                <option label="courseLevel">Foundation</option>
                <option label="courseLevel">Undergraduate</option>
                <option label="courseLevel">Postgraduate</option>
              </select>
```

In firefox and chrome i get "Foundation","Undergraduate","Postgraduate" as the options. In internet explorer i get "courseLevel","courseLevel","courseLevel". Why? and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`label` is [not being used correctly](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_option_label.asp) (only IE 7+ and Opera support it). You don't need it.

```
<label for="courseLevel">Level</label>
<select name="courseLevel" id="courseLevel">
    <option>Foundation</option>
    <option>Undergraduate</option>
    <option>Postgraduate</option>
</select>
```

What you are probably looking for is value. For example, you could assign numeric values to each of the options like so:

```
<label for="courseLevel">Level</label>
<select name="courseLevel" id="courseLevel">
    <option value='0'>Foundation</option>
    <option value='1'>Undergraduate</option>
    <option value='2'>Postgraduate</option>
</select>
```

However, you don't need them. When no values are specified, the text between `<option>` and `</option>` will be used.

Answer (score 1):

`option` tags don't need a `label` attribute. It might be the cause of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

because firefox ignores the `label` elements assigned to each option.

http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_option_label.asp , http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_option.asp

seems like only IE7+ and Opera supports this tag

Answer (score 0):

The label attribute is only supported by IE/Opera and will replace the option's innerText value.

Answer (score 0):

Your XHTML is wrong.

You actually want `<option value="">` tags; the label property makes no sense there.  Furthermore, each `value` of an `<option>` tag should be unique.  The label tag is correct there, since it corresponds to the id of the `<select>` tag and will make the drop-down menu appear when the `'Level'` text is clicked.

```
<label for="courseLevel">Level</label>
   <select name="courseLevel" id="courseLevel">
      <option value="1">Foundation</option>
      <option value="2">Undergraduate</option>
      <option value="3">Postgraduate</option>
   </select>
```